# Get method arguments using Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring AOP and have below aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.mkyong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }

}
```

Above aspect intercepts `addCustomer` method execution. `addCustomer` method takes string as an input. 
But I need to log input passed to `addCustomer` method inside `logBefore` method.
Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: What is the method signature of `addCustomer(..)`?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You have a few options:

First, you can use the [`JoinPoint#getArgs()`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs%28%29) method which returns an `Object[]` containing all the arguments of the advised method. You might have to do some casting depending on what you want to do with them.

Second, you can use the `args` pointcut expression like so:

```
// use '..' in the args expression if you have zero or more parameters at that point
@Before("execution(* com.mkyong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(..)) && args(yourString,..)")
```

then your method can instead be defined as

```
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, String yourString)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is a difference in behavior between the 2 options. The second one will only trigger if the arg exist, whereas the first one will be triggered even if the argument does not exist.

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI Haven't specified a pointcut expression for the first example. If we assume an execution of `addCustomer(..)`, sure. Can be no arguments or many.

Comment: The second option is very much handy. I had a requirement of logging the request and response as well as some other params before and after sending a request to some xyz url and without the second option, the Pointcut expression would have become very complex and unreadable.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, the value of any argument can be found using [getArgs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs%28%29)

```
@Before("execution(* com.mkyong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

   Object[] signatureArgs = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
   for (Object signatureArg: signatureArgs) {
      System.out.println("Arg: " + signatureArg);
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you have to log all args or your method have one argument, you can simply use getArgs like described in previous answers.

If you have to log a specific arg, you can annoted it and then recover its value like this :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Data {
 String methodName() default "";
}

@Aspect
public class YourAspect {

 @Around("...")
 public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
  Method method = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod();
  Object[] args = point.getArgs();
  StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    for (int argIndex = 0; argIndex < args.length; argIndex++) {
        for (Annotation paramAnnotation : parameterAnnotations[argIndex]) {
            if (!(paramAnnotation instanceof Data)) {
                continue;
            }
            Data dataAnnotation = (Data) paramAnnotation;
            if (dataAnnotation.methodName().length() > 0) {
                Object obj = args[argIndex];
                Method dataMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod(dataAnnotation.methodName());
                data.append(dataMethod.invoke(obj));
                continue;
            }
            data.append(args[argIndex]);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Examples of use :

```
public void doSomething(String someValue, @Data String someData, String otherValue) {
    // Apsect will log value of someData param
}

public void doSomething(String someValue, @Data(methodName = "id") SomeObject someData, String otherValue) {
    // Apsect will log returned value of someData.id() method
}
```

Comment: @Around("...") Isn't this pattern invalid for @Around.

Comment: `"..." `means complete with your pattern.

Comment: nice, what I was looking for

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for for my Attribute-Based Access Control evaluation!

Answer (score 12):

There is also another way if you define one pointcut for many advices it can be helpful:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.stackoverflow.MyAnnotation * *(..))")
protected void myPointcut() {
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "myPointcut() && args(someId,..)", throwing = "e")
public void afterThrowingException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception e, Integer someId) {
    System.out.println(someId.toString());
}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "myPointcut() && args(someId,..)")
public void afterSuccessfulReturn(JoinPoint joinPoint, Integer someId) {
    System.out.println(someId.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your can use either of the following methods.

```
@Before("execution(* ong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(String))")
public void logBefore1(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getArgs()[0]);
 }
```

or

```
@Before("execution(* ong.customer.bo.CustomerBo.addCustomer(String)), && args(inputString)")
public void logBefore2(JoinPoint joinPoint, String inputString) {
    System.out.println(inputString);
 }
```

joinpoint.getArgs() returns object array. Since, input is single string, only one object is returned.

In the second approach, the name should be same in expression and input parameter in the advice method i.e. `args(inputString)` and `public void logBefore2(JoinPoint joinPoint, String inputString)`

Here, `addCustomer(String)` indicates the method with one String input parameter.

Answer (score 4):

you can get method parameter and its value and if annotated with a annotation with following code:

`Map<String, Object> annotatedParameterValue = getAnnotatedParameterValue(MethodSignature.class.cast(jp.getSignature()).getMethod(), jp.getArgs());`

....

```
private Map<String, Object> getAnnotatedParameterValue(Method method, Object[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> annotatedParameters = new HashMap<>();
        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();

        int i = 0;
        for (Annotation[] annotations : parameterAnnotations) {
            Object arg = args[i];
            String name = parameters[i++].getDeclaringExecutable().getName();
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                if (annotation instanceof AuditExpose) {
                    annotatedParameters.put(name, arg);
                }
            }
        }
        return annotatedParameters;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a single String argument, do:
`joinPoint.getArgs()[0];`

Answer (score 3):

if your using @Aspect an option is add this method inside your Aspect and send the JoinPoint and the name of parameter you need.

```
private Object getParameter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String parameterName) {
    Object valueParameter = null;
    if (Objects.nonNull(joinPoint) && joinPoint.getSignature() instanceof MethodSignature
            && Objects.nonNull(parameterName) ) {
        MethodSignature method = (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
        String[] parameters = method.getParameterNames();
        for (int t = 0; t< parameters.length; t++) {
            if( Objects.nonNull(parameters[t]) && parameters[t].equals(parameterName)) {
                Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();
                valueParameter = obj[t];
            }
        }
    }
    return valueParameter;
}
```

and the call example:

```
Object parameterObject = getParameter(joinPoint, "nameClient");
if ( Objects.nonNull(parameterObject) ) {
    String parametro = String.valueOf(parameterObject);
}
```

Only need know the type of object for convert