# Pointcut entity load/persist JPA actions?

Tags: java, jpa, aop, aspect

I'd like to wrap/unwrap my Entity each time it's loaded or persisted. I got to know that I cannot do it using JPA listeners since they can only perform an action on the object and not swap it with the other. The natural solution would be to use an Aspect. But are there particular methods that I can pointcut? The thing is that the entity to be wrapped/unwrapped can be a field of another entity...

EDIT:

I found out that you **cannot** do this using Spring AOP because EntityManager is not spring-managed (why?) - see [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/21357-pointcut-on-entitymanager). To make it work I would have to define EntityManager bean explicitely but it is not recommended in that post - again, why? How to do that anyway? On the other hand why does they state that created EntityManager is application-managed? See [spring API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pointcut the getters and setter that use the entity class. Methods that retrieve entities from EntityManager, best way to achieve this is create new annotation and put over all the methods that could retrieve a instance for that class, then use the @annotation support pointcut:

> @annotation - limits matching to join points where the subject of the
>   join point (method being executed in Spring AOP) has the given
>   annotation

Also to obtain the modifying entity you could do something like this.

[Get method arguments using spring aop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660535/get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop)

Sometimes you need access in the advice body to the actual value that was returned. You can use the form of @AfterReturning that binds the return value

Comment: That was my initial approach. The problem with it is that the entity is exposed inside the object it's nested in. What is more I think that you cannot do that with Spring AOP because it works only on managed beans...