# Intercepting objects during method calls in AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following method in my `Dao` layer

`public void setApples(List<Apple> apples)`

I want to intercept the `apples` collection  every time the **method is executed** and push instances of `Apple` to a sink.

I am trying to do the same using `Aspects` now which annotation do I use to capture the concerned objects and what should be the pointcut expression? I was trying `@AfterReturning` but this is a void method how do I capture the arguments of this? I am a beginner in AOP so please excuse if this question is too trivial.

### UPDATE

The solution: [Get method arguments using spring aop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660535/get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop)

Comment: Please instead of mentioning the answer in your updated question, write your own answer and self-accept it in order to close the question. At the moment it is still shown as unanswered.

Comment: I tried that but the answer got marked as trivial and got commented so I figured if I mention the answer in the question people can find help

Answer (score 0):

you have two options, either create a spring aop proxy (1) bean or use aspectj (2).

1. would be used in runtime and it would create a proxy "wrapper" that would intercept the calls to method. take a look at ProxyFactoryBean/BeanNameAutoProxyCreator (advice), NameMatchMethodPointcut (pointcut).
2. using AspectJ create the same intercepter. take a look at < aop:pointcut> and < aop:aspect>

in both cases you need to intercept before method execution. so either use < aop:before> or MethodBeforeAdvice