# Spring AOP: How to pass argument from called method to advice method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am designing a system where I need to pass argument from the called method to the advice method. I am providing a simple code to make the point clear -

//AOPMain.java:

```
public class AOPMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext cxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    Employee emp = cxt.getBean("employee", Employee.class);

    emp.sayHello();
}
```

}

//Employee.java:

```
public class Employee {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    System.out.println("getName");
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    System.out.println("setName");
    this.name = name;
}

public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    //How to pass argument to afterAdvice
}
```

}

//Logging.java:

```
 @Aspect
public class Logging {

    @Pointcut("execution(public void sayHello())") 
    public void doSomething(){}         

    @After("doSomething()")             
    public void afterAdvice() {
        System.out.println("After Advice");
        //Depending on the argument passed, send notification
    }
}
```

How I can design this system? I know that there are ways to pass the argument to advice method from AOPMain itself using &&args(), but I am not able to find any sample code for this specific problem.

I know it's violating the basic design principle, that the advice method is not loosely coupled. So does Spring support this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to do (you post some code but without any pointer about what it should do,,,) - But let me guess: you try to apply an second aspect (`afterAdvice`) to an first level aspect (`doSomething`)?

Comment: Hi @Ralph, thanks for replying back. Actually I am designing a notification system. The main method will call a checkThreshold method in another class and if the threshold limit is reached, then the advice method will be automatically called with proper String argument. The advice method will send the proper notification to the external engine. Hence I was stuck how to achieve this feat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get information from the advised method:

- let it return a value and used that returned value in the advice:

  ```
  public Arg sayHello() {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      //How to pass argument to afterAdvice
      Arg arg = ...;
      return arg;
  }

  @AfterReturning(pointcut="doSomething()", returning="retval")             
  public void afterAdvice(Object retval) {
      System.out.println("After Advice");
      // use retval here ...
  }
  ```
- use a JoinPoint to get access to the original object on which method was called, and pass arg as an object attribute:

  ```
  public void sayHello() {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      //How to pass argument to afterAdvice
      this.arg = ...;
  }

  @After("doSomething()")             
  public void afterAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {
      System.out.println("After Advice");
      Employee emp = (Employee) jp.getTarget();
      // use emp.arg here ...
  }
  ```

  This one only makes sense if the advised object is statefull - do not considere to use it on a service or controller that are shared objects...

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! Your suggestion has solved my problem! I found that there is a different way as well. Instead of returning a value from the advised method, I can throw a custom exception and in the advice method I can use AfterThrowing clause. So AfterReturning and AfterThrowing are the two ways the advised and the advice methods can communicate. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
@After("doSomething()")             
public void afterAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
   System.out.println("After Advice");
   //joinPoint.getArgs(); 
   //Depending on the argument passed, send notification
}
```

Doesn't solve your problem? Refer [get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660535/get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop) to know more.

Comment: Hi @Lovababu I have checked the example that you have provided. But here inside the logBefore() method we are accessing the arguments originally passed to the addCustomer() method (from the main). But I want to pass argument (a String variable) from addCustomer() to logBefore(). Can it be achieved by joinPoint.getArgs()? Let me try.