# Override HttpMessageConverter for Spring RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> devicedataList, @RequestHeader(value="special_code") String specialCode) {
// Implementation details
}
```

Each instance of MobileDeviceData that gets created needs to have a param field filled in with the RequestHeader special_code.

How would I go about doing this so that it is fully populated by the time the flagDevice method body gets called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is non trivial.

An `HttpMessageConverter` is already provided that deserializes the JSON, that's the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. It has access to request headers. You could extend that class to also use the headers for deserialization (this is extremely difficult to do generically, as opposed to only for `MobileDeviceData`).

You could use Spring AOP, intercept the method, [retrieve the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660535/get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop), cast to the appropriate types, and assign the value yourself.

The solution I would go for is the simplest: do it yourself in the handler method. Loop the the `List` and use a corresponding setter to set the `specialCode` for each `MobileDeviceData`.

Another option is to define your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` specifically for `List<MobileDeviceData>` parameters that need to be constructed from header vales.

Comment: Thanks. Will probably go for the trivial solution in that case.